# urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline doesn't always override the default 5s

Tags: google-app-engine

When uploading to flickr, my app intermittently (about 10% of the time? small sample size) times out after exactly 5s, even after overriding the deadline.  Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

If you embed AppEngine libraries, you can patch the url fetch and set 60 seconds for the deadline. It is in the file httplib2/**init**.py (2 modifications) :

```
       def fixed_fetch(url, payload=None, method="GET", headers={},
                       allow_truncated=False, follow_redirects=True,
                      deadline=60):
           return fetch(url, payload=payload, method=method, headers=headers,
                        allow_truncated=allow_truncated,
                       follow_redirects=follow_redirects, deadline=60,
                        validate_certificate=validate_certificate)
       return fixed_fetch
```

Answer (score -2):

Opposite to what Maël proposes, to adequately handle the situation, you should reduce (or just leave to default) the deadline time for the URLFetch calls, and afterwards catch exceptions and retry a number of times doing an exponential backoff. The idea is that if the server is down temporarily (as it may be happening in your case), it is not overwhelmed with requests hitting at the same time when it comes back up. You can see a brief explanation of this practice [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff).

Alternatively, you could use the [Sockets API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/#making_httplib_use_sockets) for the httplib to use sockets.